# React native app suddenly closes - no reason?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an app in react native and I'm using expo.
After a while the app suddenly crashes and exits. The user is still logged in (so it's not the code that kicks the user out) and no error is displayed.

Have anyone seen something like this before?

I looked for a solution online, and the only clue that I found is that maybe I have a broken package in my project that causes memory leak.

This is my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.5",
    "@hilma/auth": "^0.2.37",
    "@hilma/auth-native": "^0.6.26",
    "@hilma/tools": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^5.12.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "css-tree": "1.0.0-alpha.39",
    "emoji-mart": "^3.0.0",
    "expo": "^38.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-camera": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~1.1.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.3.5",
    "gapi-client": "0.0.3",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "milsymbol": "^2.0.0",
    "mobx": "^6.0.1",
    "mobx-react": "^7.0.0",
    "modal-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
    "navigation": "^5.3.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd-grid": "^0.1.3-alpha",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-clear-app-cache": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-draggable": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-expo-viewport-units": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-viewport-units": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13"
  },
```

Is any of this packages is broken? I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: It can be caused by many reasons, you should check your logs with adb logcat and reproduce your steps